# Telerik Kendo grid aggregates not working when DataSource is Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm testing the Telerik grid for MVC, but I can't seem to make it work the way I need to.

Installation was a breeze and I got the grid to show data as a result of an executed stored procedure. It paginates, filters and sorts.

The problem is that I need it to display the aggregate SUM in one of the columns, and I've been trying to understand how the documentation example works with no luck so far.

I'm using the following DataSource:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Server().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.totalMoney))
            .Aggregates(aggregates => aggregates.Add(p => p.totalMoney).Sum()
            ))
```

With this DataSource everything works fine, but the ClientFooterTemplate shows total = 0.

I've tried a different DataSource which makes the sum work:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.oper_numero))
            .Aggregates(aggregates => aggregates.Add(p => p.oper_monto).Sum()
            ))
```

But the problem is that I lose the paging, I suppose because the grid can't reach the data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, for those who are stuck with this, Server binding does NOT allow aggregates. You have to go with Ajax binding instead.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? I am having problems with this as well?

Comment: @Anokrize I got in contact with the Telerik support; they informed me that aggregates are not available when using server side binding. I went with ajax binding and it works fine.